# How can I populate a postgres table using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, golang-migrate

I am trying to populate a postgres table with data from a csv file when running `docker-compose up -d`, however, all the methods I have tried end up saying the file could not be found.

One of the ways I was trying was using `golang-migrate` and the migrations to create the table work, but when attempting to run `COPY customers FROM 'customers.csv' CSV HEADER;` it gives the following error:

```
error: migration failed: could not open file "customers.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

My migrations step looks like this:

```
  migrations:
    image: migrate/migrate
    command: -database postgres://postgres:password@database:5432/database?sslmode=disable -path /migrations up
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/migrations
```

The `customers.csv` file is located in my `migrations` directory along with my migration sql files to create and drop the table (both of which work fine) along with a third migration sql file with the `COPY` query. I was under the impression that by setting the volume to `./migrations:/migrations` it would map all files from my `./migrations` directory in my project to `/migrations` in the container, so I really don't understand how it can't find the file.

Is there something else I need to do to get my csv file to my docker container or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try passing the entire path in the COPY command like `/migrations/customer.csv` or `./customer.csv` maybe it will work

Comment: Other way I prefer is to do migration as a part of your application startup and avoid this extra step through docker-compose setup

Answer (score 0):

It seems the migration files themselves are found correctly, via the `-path /migrations` flag, but this doesn't change the working directory. The `COPY customers FROM 'customers.csv' CSV HEADER;` command will try to read `customers.csv` from the working directory, since it is not an absolute path.

You could either change the command to `COPY customers FROM '/migrations/customers.csv' CSV HEADER;` or change the working directory of the container via the [`working_dir`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#working_dir) docker-compose option.

```
  migrations:
    image: migrate/migrate
    command: -database postgres://postgres:password@database:5432/database?sslmode=disable -path /migrations up
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/migrations
    working_dir: /migrations
```

The second option may be slightly nicer, as it doesn't require a SQL code change.